# Multiple Series Charts with WPFtoolkit

Tags: c#, wpf, wpftoolkit, silverlight-toolkit

Does anyone of you know the way to create multiple series charts with wpftoolkit? In a nutshell what I want is to have more dependent values for the same independent value. So far I couldn't find any comprehensive mechanism to get this working. Any help is deeply appreciated.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You might want to consider the [alternatives](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1152016/best-charting-tool-for-silverlight-and-wpf), from past experience the charting components in the WPF Toolkit are extremely rigid and hard to extend. I've also had numerous issues with bugs in the toolkit and active development seems to have completely ground to a halt. There are some very good free alternative that are worth considering.

Comment: Hi Tom, thanks for the answer. I have no other option than going ahead with the WPFtoolkit. We are almost halfway through with a BI product development and will have no other way than using the toolkit. If you come across any favorable answer for my previous question, even if it partially fulfills the requirement, do share it with us. Thanks again.

Answer (score 21):

If you want a Chart with two `LineSeries`

[image]

You may have 2 different lists in your .cs file filed with data:

```
List<KeyValuePair<DateTime, int>> llistaGastats = new List<KeyValuePair<DateTime, int>>();
List<KeyValuePair<DateTime, int>> llistaPreu = new List<KeyValuePair<DateTime, int>>();
```

Then you have to create another list to group those two lists:

```
var dataSourceList = new List<List<KeyValuePair<DateTime, int>>>();
dataSourceList.Add(llistaGastats);
dataSourceList.Add(llistaPreu);
```

And assign it to the `DataContext`

```
lineChart.DataContext = dataSourceList;
```

In your .xaml file you should create a `Chart` with two `LineSeries` and get the value of each Line using the `ItemSource` field.

Here is the .xaml:

```
<chartingToolkit:Chart Name="lineChart"
                                       Title="Consum KW" 
                                       VerticalAlignment="Top" 
                                       Margin="0,58,58,0" 
                                       Height="382"
                                       Grid.Column="1">
                <chartingToolkit:LineSeries Name="KWG"
                                                Title="KW Gastats"  
                                                DependentValuePath="Value" 
                                                IndependentValuePath="Key"
                                                ItemsSource="{Binding [0]}"
                                                IsSelectionEnabled="True"/>
                <chartingToolkit:LineSeries Name="KWP" 
                                                Title="Preu KW"  
                                                DependentValuePath="Value" 
                                                IndependentValuePath="Key"
                                                ItemsSource="{Binding [1]}"
                                                IsSelectionEnabled="True" />
            </chartingToolkit:Chart>
```

`ItemsSource="{Binding [0]}"` Binds the first item in the list assigned to the DataContext.
`ItemsSource="{Binding [1]}"` Binds the second

Answer (score 2):

Beat Kiener has a great article on [Databinding Multi-Series Charts](http://blog.thekieners.com/2010/02/07/databinding-multi-series-charts/). In it, he implements his own `MultiChart` class, derived from `Chart`.

This may be too late for you, but at least it may help others.

Answer (score 1):

create a datatable with a column for each series , add five column series(in case of column chart,and five series) to the chart , with DependentValueBinding to each column name, set ItemsSource to datatable( ItemsSource is same for each column series).

Let me know if you want me to add the code.