# How can I bind an axis of a chart to a specific index of a List()?

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, xaml, wpftoolkit

I'm attempting to create a chart using the WPF Toolkit where the Y Axis is being updated by values in a `List()`. I'm trying access the value via a specific index. Currently, binding to the index of the `List()` rather than an `int` creates a "No suitable axis is available for plotting the dependent value." exception.

Here's what I have so far, note my attempt to get the `DependentValuePath` to access an index:

```
<Charting:LineSeries VerticalAlignment="Stretch" 
                     HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" 
                     ItemsSource="{Binding Path=MemoryStats}" 
                     IndependentValuePath="Timestamp" 
                     DependentValuePath="ByteCount[0]"
                     Title="Data Points">
```

This is what `MemoryStats` values consist of in the code behind:

```
public List<int> ByteCount { get; set; }
public DateTime Timestamp { get; set; }
```

The chart works fine when the LineSeries in the XAML has the property `DependentValuePath="ByteCount"` and when the codebehind uses a simple int:

```
public int ByteCount { get; set; }
public DateTime Timestamp { get; set; }
```

How do I get it to bind to an index of a `List()` rather than an `int`?

**EDIT**

I have been able to grab the specific value in the list from the code behind by naming its index, but there will be multiple `LineSeries` generated dynamically when the chart is created. I would like to bind each one to an index of a `List<int>()`, which I recreate every second or so.

Here is the full method that `MemoryStats` uses to update the UI. It is working by updating all of the `LineSeries` Y values to the single ByteCount `int`, so currently all of the lines look the same.

```
    public class MemorySample
    {
        public static MemorySample Generate(List<int> dataPoints)
        {

            return new MemorySample
            {
                ByteCount = dataPoints[0],
                Timestamp = DateTime.Now
            };
        }

        public int ByteCount { get; set; }
        public DateTime Timestamp { get; set; }
    }
```

Of course, I'd like all of the `LineSeries` to be different. I would like to have the X axis of each `LineSeries` of the chart be the `TimeStamp` (so they all have the same TimeStamp) and the various `LineSeries` have their Y axis values be updated by a `List()` of integers, each using a separate index of the `List()`

I'll try to implement a type converter, but I'm not entirely sure when/where to do that.

**EDIT 2**

I got it to work the way I wanted it to! I found a lot of help [from this S.O. question regarding using multiple series in a line chart.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5002786/multiple-series-charts-with-wpftoolkit)

It appears as if a type converter would work as well, so Shimrod has got the question answered. However, what I ended up doing is set the binding of the LineSeries' `ItemSource` to an index and then retrieved the data of the content of that index.

So, here's what the `LineSeries` looks like:

```
        <Charting:LineSeries VerticalAlignment="Stretch" 
                            HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" 
                            ItemsSource="{Binding [0]}" 
                            IndependentValuePath="X" 
                            DependentValuePath="Y"
                            Title="Data Points">
        </Charting:LineSeries>
```

Note the index in the `ItemSource` binding. In the code behind, I set the `DataContext` of the control to an `ObservableCollection`, which holds an object that inherits from 'IList' (which you could use any object that does so), and that object holds the object that contains the properties `X` and `Y` properties.

```
   public ObservableCollection<InheritsFromIList<ObjectWithXandYProperties>> VariableDataContextIsSetTo { get; set; }
```

Accessing a specific index of the `ObservableCollection` will return the list. Then, the items in that list display on the chart.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest way I think to do this would be to add a property in your class which would be the `int` value of the `List`.

e.g.

```
int val { get { return ByteCount[0]; } }
```

Or you could also create a converter which would take the list as binding and the index as parameter, and return the desired value.

For example *(I haven't tried this)*:

```
public class ElementOfListConverter : IValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
    {
        if (value is IList && parameter is int)
        {
            var lst = value as IList;
            int pos = (int)parameter;

            if (lst.Count >= pos)
            {
                return lst[pos];
            }
        }

        return null;
    }

    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```

---

## Edit

These are the steps to use the converter:

1. Create the class (ElementOfListConverter), as shown before.
2. Add a new xml namespace pointing towards the location of your converter. E.g.
   `xmlns:local="clr-namespace:WpfApplication2"`
3. In the resources of your Window (or UserControl), add a reference to your converter, like this:

   ```
   <Window.Resources>
       <local:ElementOfListConverter x:Key="ElemOfList" />
   </Window.Resources>
   ```
4. In your binding, specify the converter to use (*using its key*)
   `{Binding YourElement, Converter={StaticResource ElemOfList}, ConverterParameter=0}`

The pro for this method is that you can specify the index of the element directly in the xaml.  You could also bind this value to some other value using a [`MultiBinding`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.data.multibinding.aspx) and a [`MultiValueConverter`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms613613.aspx).  (see [this question on S.O.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15309008/binding-converterparameter) if you need more information.

Comment: I am not too familiar with where to implement a type converter, but I will give it a go. I will update my question with a little more detail if that will help. I have not implemented the solution correctly yet, but for now I will chalk it up to my own inexperience and will accept the answer.

Comment: I added a sample code, don't hesitate to tell me if you need more info !